# Implementation of two methods

Tags: java

In my application I have two classes called Platform and another Organizer.

Platform class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

public class Platform {
private List<User> users;
private List<Competition> competitions;

public Platform() {
    /**
     * PR1 Ex 2.1: We need to initialize the list of users
    */
    users = new ArrayList<User>();
}

User findUser(String username) { 
    /**
     * PR1 Ex 2.1: Implementation of method findUser to find a user in the list users by username
    */
    User user = null;

    Iterator<User> itr = this.users.iterator();      
    while(itr.hasNext() && user == null) {
        User u = itr.next();
        if(u.getUserName().equals(username)) {
            user = u;
        }
    }

    return user;
}

public User registerUser(String username, String password, String fullname) {        
    /**
     * PR1 Ex 2.1: Register a new user, checking that it does not exist 
    */
    User newUser = null;

    // Check if the user is new or already exists
    User queryUser = findUser(username);

    if(queryUser==null) {
        newUser = new User(this, username, password, fullname);
        this.users.add(newUser);
    }

    return newUser;
}

public User login(String username, String password) {    
    /**
     * PR1 Ex 2.2: Login an already existing user
    */
    User user = null;

    // Find the user in the list of registered users
    User queryUser = findUser(username);        

    // If the user exists, check the password
    if(queryUser!=null && queryUser.checkPassword(password)) {
        user = queryUser;
    }

    return user;        
}    

public Integer getNumUsers() {
    /**
     * PR1 Ex 2.1: Required for test, to check if a new user is registered 
    */
    return this.users.size();
}

public Integer getNumCompetitions() {        
    return null;
}

public Message sendMessage(User from, String to, String subject, String message) throws CompetitionException {               
    User receiver = findUser(to);
if (to == null) {
    throw new CompetitionException(CompetitionException.SENDER_NOT_FOUND);
}
else if(receiver == null ) {
    throw new CompetitionException(CompetitionException.SENDER_NOT_FOUND); //Aquí debes lanza el tipo de excepción apropiado de tu lógica de negocio
}
Message  m = new Message(this, this, subject, message);
return m;
}
public void registerCompetition(Competition competition) {

}    

public List<Competition> getOpenCompetitions() {        
    return null;
}

private void evaluateAll() {

}

public void run() {
    // Simulates system call for evaluation
    evaluateAll();
  }
 }
```

And Class Organizer

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Organizer extends User {
private List<Competition> competitions;

public Organizer(User user) {
    super(user);
    // Initialize the list of competitions
    competitions = new ArrayList<Competition>();                
}

public void removeSubmission(Submission submission) {
    /* NOT IMPLEMENTED */
}

public boolean sendMessage(Competition competition, String subject, String message) {
    /* NOT IMPLEMENTED */
    return false;
}

public Competition newCompetition(String title, float target) {        
   Competition s =new Competition(platform, this, title, target);
}

public void closeCompetition(Competition competition) {

}

public List<Competition> getCompetitions() {        
    return this.competitions;
}

private void updateCompetitions() {

 }
}
```

I want to implement the newCompetition method of the Organizer class so that it gives the data by parameter of a
New competition:

--Instantiate an object for the new competition and then register the competition on platform using the registerCompetition

The method of the class Organizer newCompetition I have it

```
  public Competition newCompetition(String title, float target) {        
   Competition s =new Competition(platform, this, title, target);
   competitions.add(s);
   return s;
}
```

How do I register the competition with Platform's `registerCompetition` method?

I have the following class of tests and I would like to know how to implement those methods to pass them

Class Test

```
public class PR2_Ex2_1_Test {

private final String username1 = "username1";
private final String password1 = "password1";
private final String fullName1 = "Test User 1";

private final String username2 = "username2";
private final String password2 = "password2";
private final String fullName2 = "Test User 2";

private final String comp_title1 = "Approximate number PI";
private final float comp_target1 = 3.141592653589793238f;

private Platform platform = null;
private User u1 = null;    
private User u2 = null;    

public PR2_Ex2_1_Test() {        
}

@BeforeClass
public static void setUpClass() {

}

@AfterClass
public static void tearDownClass() {
}

@Before
public void setUp() {
    // Create the test scenario
    platform = new Platform();

    // Register new users
    u1 = platform.registerUser(username1, password1, fullName1); 
    u2 = platform.registerUser(username2, password2, fullName2);
}

@After
public void tearDown() {

}  

@Test
public void createCompetitionObject() {   
    Organizer o1 = u1.asOrganizer();

    Competition c1 = o1.newCompetition(comp_title1, comp_target1);

    assertNotNull(c1);
    assertEquals(o1, c1.getOwner());        
    assertTrue(c1.isOpen()); 
    assertNotNull(c1.getSubmissions());
    assertEquals(0, c1.getSubmissions().size());
}

@Test
public void duplicatedCompetitionObjects() {   
    Organizer o1 = u1.asOrganizer();        
    Competition c1 = o1.newCompetition(comp_title1, comp_target1);
    Competition c2 = o1.newCompetition(comp_title1, comp_target1);

    // If id is correct, they cannot be equals
    assertThat(c1, is(not(equalTo(c2))));

    // Id cannot depend on the owner
    Organizer o2 = u2.asOrganizer();   
    Competition c3 = o2.newCompetition(comp_title1, comp_target1);               
    assertThat(c1, is(not(equalTo(c3))));        
}

@Test
public void AssociatedObjects() {   
    Organizer o1 = u1.asOrganizer();        
    Competition c1 = o1.newCompetition(comp_title1, comp_target1);       

    assertEquals(new Integer(1), platform.getNumCompetitions());
    assertEquals(1, o1.getCompetitions().size());
  }
}
```

Comment: what should your registerCompetition method do?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer  I'm going to edit better, so I put the test set that I must pass and maybe my question is better understood

Comment: for me it looks like you "register" the platform to the competition. now you could iterate over your list and look if the platforms match. if yes, you "register" the competition on the platform